# Графики seaborn в цикле чередуются нормальные рисунки с пустыми

Tags: python, циклы, seaborn

Строю графики в цикле. Если делаю

```
sns.boxplot(x = df_proba[clm])
```

то все нормально.

Но если заменяю на

```
sns.displot (x=df_proba[clm], kde= True)
```

то первый рисунок идет пустым, затем нормальный, затем опять пустой, затем опять нормальный и т.д.

Как избавиться от пустых рисунков?

```
import seaborn as sns

df_proba = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3)),
                columns=list('ABC'))

    my_columns=list('ABC')
    n = 3
    i=0
    for clm in my_columns:
        i+=1
        plt.figure(figsize=(4, 16))
        plt.subplot(n, 1, i)
        sns.displot (x=df_proba[clm], kde= True)
        # sns.boxplot(x = df_proba[clm])
```

Answer (score 0):

displot надо писать через t - distplot